# Spring security kerberos validate token error

Tags: spring, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

I'm using Spring Security Kerberos 1.0.0.RELEASE with JDK 7, Spring Security 3.2.7.RELEASE and Spring Framework 4.1.6.RELEASE to process authentication in my app. But i always getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: null
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:67) ~[spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.ietf.jgss.GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(GSSHeader.java:97) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:306) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:162) ~[spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator$KerberosValidateAction.run(SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java:152) ~[spring-security-kerberos-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:1.0.0.RELEASE]
```

My Spring config is

```
<bean id="kerberosAuthenticationService" class="com.test.app.authentication.service.impl.KerberosAuthenticationServiceImpl">
    <property name="customKerberosTicketValidator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator">
            <property name="servicePrincipal" value="${authentication.kerberos.principal}" />
            <property name="keyTabLocation" value="${authentication.kerberos.keytab}" />
            <property name="debug" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- OVERRIDING DEFAULT KRB configuration -->
<bean class="org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig">
    <property name="debug" value="true" />
    <property name="krbConfLocation" value="classpath:kerberos/krb5.conf" />
</bean>
```

And the authenticated method look like here

---

```
 try {
        base64Token = header.substring(10);
        kerberosTicket = Base64.decode(base64Token.trim().getBytes());
        KerberosServiceRequestToken authenticationRequest = new KerberosServiceRequestToken(kerberosTicket);
        byte[] token = authenticationRequest.getToken();

        KerberosTicketValidation kerberosTicketValidation = this.customKerberosTicketValidator.validateTicket(token);
        userName = kerberosTicketValidation.username();

        LOGGER.debug("USername {} ", userName);

    } -------
```

How can i fix this error?
Thx fr yoour reply
Regards

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and expand your question accordingly.

Comment: Please post relevant code.